# Selecting Mysql Meta_Value in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Why the result return is null? What is wrong? If I use this consult on directly phpmyadmin, the result is correctly.

```
<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?>

<?php
$get_thumb = $wpdb->get_var
( "SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = $postid AND  `meta_key` = '_wp_attached_file'" );
echo "<p>Thumb URL: {$get_thumb}</p>";
?>
```

[image: PhpMyAdmin Consult!]

Comment: what type of script is this code being hooked into? Is it a page, post, shortcode script?

Comment: There is an es.stackoverflow.com and a pt.stackoverflow.com which can be also useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the $wpdb->prepare() statement to ensure the SQL query is generated correct and the $get_thumb variable is correctly set in the query.

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
$get_thumb = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( 
 "SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = %s AND  `meta_key` = '_wp_attached_file'",$postid));
echo "<p>Thumb URL: {$get_thumb}</p>";
```

Again you can always log the SQL string generated by prepare() to ensure it matches your expectations. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples for more examples.

Comment: i think the problem have relation with get_the_id();, because when i set $postid = 10608 this work perfectly.

Comment: You almost have the right code - the `%s` should be `%d` (it's a number, not a string you're passing as post_id)

Comment: If you try to `echo` your `$postid` just after you define it, does it look correct? Maybe you are not in the loop properly - remember $post must be defined for get_the_ID() to work. I'm asking because you mentioned it may be a problem with that.

Comment: Yes sir! If I use echo after setting it, the result appears perfectly

Ex: <?php echo $ postid; ?>

The return is correct!

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax has some trouble, so here's your original query revised.

```
<?php
     $get_thumb = $wpdb->get_var( 
         "
          SELECT meta_value 
          FROM wp_postmeta 
          WHERE post_id = " . $postid . " AND meta_key = _wp_attached_file
         "
      );
      echo "<p>Thumb URL: {$get_thumb}</p>";
?>
```

I made sure the PHP is echoing correctly inside the query - I am not sure if that's a problem you were having.

I do recommend the prepared query too. Here is it with what I think is correct syntax (I found it was helpful to prepare items by putting them in a $query_arg_array). See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb.

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
$query_arg_array = [$postid];
$get_thumb = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( 
 "
  SELECT meta_value 
  FROM wp_postmeta 
  WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key = _wp_attached_file
  ",
  $query_arg_array
));

echo "<p>Thumb URL: {$get_thumb}</p>";
```

If that prepared query didn't work, try putting `$postid` directly as argument instead of the `$query_arg_array`.

Remember SQL is super sensitive so even an extra space can throw off your query.

Comment: true - Remember SQL is super sensitive so even an extra space can throw off your query.

Comment: Does it work in either of those examples if you directly place your post_id into the query? (like the direct number), or define post_id manually?